# How to use proc summary and keep all variables (without naming them)

Tags: sas, summary

I want to sum over a specific variable in my dataset, without loosing all the other columns. I have tried the following code:

```
proc summary data=work.test nway missing; 
class var_1 var_2 ; *groups;
var salary; 
id _character_ _numeric_; * keeps all variables;
output out=test2(drop=_:) sum= ;
run;
```

But it does not seem to sum properly, and for the "salary" column I'm just left with the value of the last value in each group (var_1 and var_2). If I remove

```
 id _character_ _numeric_;
```

it works fine, but I loose all other columns.

**Example**:

*data*:

```
data salary;
   input name $ dept $ Salary Sex $;
   datalines;
John Sales 23 M
John Sales 43 M
Mary Acctng 21 F
;
```

*desired output*:

John Sales 66 M

Mary Acctng 21 F

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data looks like and what your desired output would be?

Comment: without an example is difficult but try removing `nway`

Comment: Example added. Removing nway does not work :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want.  You still get warnings about name conflicts and variables being dropped but at least the ones you want are kept.  The ID statement is depreciated in favor in the new and better IDGROUP output statement option.

You could add the AUTONAME option to the output statement if you wanted PROC SUMMARY to automatically rename the conflicting variables.

```
data salary;
   input name $ dept $ Salary Sex $;
   datalines;
John Sales 23 M
John Sales 43 M
Mary Acctng 21 F
;;;;
   run; 
proc print;
   run;
proc summary nway missing; 
   class name dept; 
   var salary; 
   output out=test2(drop=_:) sum= idgroup(out(_all_)=);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! much appreciated!

Comment: Nice!  Putting the `sum` statement before `idgroup`  gets around the problem of using `id`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data salary;
   input name $ dept $ Salary Sex $;
   datalines;
John Sales 23 M
John Sales 43 M
Mary Acctng 21 F
; 

proc sql;
    create table salary2 as
    select *, 
        monotonic() as n, 
        sum(salary) as sum_salary 
        from salary 
        group by name 
        having max(n)=n;
quit;
```

Comment: I specified "without naming them" in the question title, but I apologize for not underlining it further. I have very many variables, you see.

Comment: Sorry! I made an edit that allows you to retain other variables without explicitly naming them.

Comment: This is actually great! +1

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that SAS did this, but the problem appears to lie in the fact that the `id` statement takes preference over the `var` statement.  By including all variables in the `id` statement, all the output is showing is the maximum value for each variable, including Salary.

One option is to pull a list of the variables not included in the `class` or `var` statements from `dictionary.columns`, then use that list in the `id` statement.  Just be aware that `proc summary` runs in memory and I have come across out of memory problems in the past when many variables have been included in the `id` statement

```
data salary;
   input name $ dept $ Salary Sex $;
   datalines;
John Sales 23 M
John Sales 43 M
Mary Acctng 21 F
; 

proc sql noprint;
select name into :cols separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where   libname='WORK' 
        and 
        memname='SALARY'
        and
        name not in ('name','Salary');
quit;

%put &cols.;

proc summary data=salary nway missing;
class name;
var salary;
id &cols.;
output out=want (drop=_:) sum=;
run;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. This answers my question. I would ideally like a method without the extra proc sql step, but if it is not possible, then...